# String index out of bounds? Where?

Tags: java, exception, for-loop, runtime-error, java.lang.class

This is my code for finding the no. of vowels in a string:

```
{
    String inyo=inpeo.getText().toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(inyo); // Just checking for an empty string

    int vowcount=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=inyo.length();i++)
 {           
        char rol=inyo.charAt(i);
        if(rol=='o'||'u'==rol||rol=='a'||rol=='e'||rol=='i')
        {
            vowcount=vowcount+1;
            System.out.println(vowcount);
        }

        numout.setText(""+vowcount);

    }
}
```

Now, nothing is wrong with the output here-it **finds the exact no. of vowels** as I intended. But it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
at WordCheck.jButton2ActionPerformed(WordCheck.java:147)
// Extra errors removed as they're irrelevant to my issue
```

As a result, there is no way of reusing the program other than closing and restarting it. when the output is coming out as desired, why am I getting this error? I don't get any empty Strings, either.

Comment: `i<=inyo.length()` here.

Comment: You need to write i<inyo.length()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last iteration of the `for` loop is causing the exception (when `i == inyo.length()`). Simply replace it with:

```
for(int i=0; i<inyo.length(); i++)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. One question though: how come my operator wrecked things up?

Comment: The comparison operator `i<=inyo.length()`

Comment: The index of a character starts with zero. The last character is at index `inyo.length() - 1`.

Answer (score 3):

`i<=inyo.length()` here. The String index starts from 0. The length count starts from one. So, the last index of a String is 4 when its length is 5.

It should be

`i<inyo.length()`

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is going one too far, this

```
for(int i=0;i<=inyo.length();i++)
```

should be

```
for(int i=0;i<inyo.length();i++)
```

Note that when `i == invo.length()` it's passed the end of the array, because Java starts indexing with `0`.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop should be

```
for(int i=0; i<inyo.length(); i++)
```

Presently when it goes to the last iteration the index of the string is 4 whereas `inyo.length()` is 5. Hence it results in out of bounds.